# Unusual JSON construct

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am supposed to read the following JSON response:

```
ValueFilters:[
{field:"amount", comparitor:"GREATER", "value": 0},
{operator:"AND"},
{field:"id", comparitor:"LESS", "value": 5}]
```

If it did not contain 'operator' object then I would not have any problem, but with it how do I construct the equivalent C# object?

Comment: Some online json to c# converter could help, f.e: [link](https://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: It's more complicated as each object in json array has different shape. You can always deserialize it as `dynamic` if strong typing is not critical for you. Otherwise you need to implement your own [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Comment: Another way would be to put all 4 fields as nullable in one type. For the first and third lines, 3 of them would be non-null, and for the second those 3 would be null and the `operator` field would be non-null. Your code would need to observe and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your example, the JSON is not valid JSON. To make it valid, one must add quotes to each of the property names such as `field` to `"field"`. Once that is done the Json can be parsed:

```
{
  "ValueFilters": [
    {
      "field": "amount",
      "comparitor": "GREATER",
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "operator": "AND"
    },
    {
      "field": "id",
      "comparitor": "LESS",
      "value": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

By taking that valid Json above it can be serialized into these C# classes:

```
public class Filters
{
    public List<ValueFilter> ValueFilters { get; set; }   
}

public class ValueFilter
{
    [JsonPropertyName("operator")]        // Handle the C# `operator` keyword.
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    
    public string field { get; set; }

    public string comparitor { get; set; } // Misspell -> comparator

    public int value { get; set; }

}
```

Using your favorite derializer would look like this, *.Net 5 System.Text.Json shown*:

```
var filter = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Filters>(data);
```

Which when deserialized you have 3 `ValueFilter` items. By checking whether the `Operator` property is not null or not, the future code knows what to do with the data.

| Operator | field | comparitor | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | amount | GREATER | 0 |
| AND | null | null | 0 |
| null | id | LESS | 5 |